# Can you forward style properties in svelte?

Tags: svelte

I'm new to svelte. I like that i can set individual style elements like

```
<div style:color='red' />
```

My question is there a way to forward these types of style properties to child components? To get a feel for it I'm building a small ui library and having this ability would make the components a lot more versatile.

Example
Row.svelte

```
<div class='row'>
   <slot></slot>
</div>
```

App.svelte

```
<Row style:color='red'>
    Hello World!
</Row>
```

This is the type of thing I'm hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to my knowledge. `style:...` is just syntactic sugar for adding a property to the `style` attribute.

So if you want to access the style of a wrapped element you can export a property for that or use the automatically created `$$props`/`$$restProps` (which is generally not recommended).

```html
<script>
  export let style = '';
</script>
<div class='row' {style}> ...
```

```html
<Row style="color: red"> ...
```